# spring boot project running issue

Tags: java, spring-boot

I created spring boot starter project using "spring tool suite". when i am running project, index.jsp page not loading. but index.html can load nicely.

my folder structure as below

[image]

my home controller is

```
package com.programmingfree.springservice;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "index";
    }

}
```

how i run `index.jsp`

Comment: Have you checked out the documentation about the limitations with JSPs and executable JARs? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations. There is also a sample available: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.5.9.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp

Answer (score 0):

You are using the default configuration for spring boot, take a look at `ThymeleafProperties.java`, `.html` is the default setting for suffix:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(
    prefix = "spring.thymeleaf"
)
public class ThymeleafProperties {
    private static final Charset DEFAULT_ENCODING = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    private static final MimeType DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE = MimeType.valueOf("text/html");
    public static final String DEFAULT_PREFIX = "classpath:/templates/";
    public static final String DEFAULT_SUFFIX = ".html";
    private boolean checkTemplate = true;
    private boolean checkTemplateLocation = true;
    private String prefix = "classpath:/templates/";
    private String suffix = ".html";
    private String mode = "HTML5";
    //......
}
```

So you have to customize your config in application.properties:

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/  
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.jsp
```

Comment: a JSP isn't a Thymeleaf template so that won't work.

Comment: Dear Dave, can i use html front end with Angular, for this project.

Comment: Seems I have misunderstood a thymeleaf, thanks. @ M. Deinum

Comment: what do you mean, the above answer should help. @user1177842

Answer (score 0):

Do you have next lines in application.properties?

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Links to resources are rewritten at runtime in template, thanks to a ResourceUrlEncodingFilter, auto-configured for Thymeleaf and FreeMarker. You should manually declare this filter when using JSPs. [spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html)